# Why don't I see multiple console.log() actions when bubbling up or propagating down with event listener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('div.container');


containers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log('I am fired');
  }, true);
});

// containers.forEach(container => {
//   container.addEventListener('click', e => {
//     console.log('I am fired');
//   }, false);
// });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="container" data-letter="A">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-letter="B">
    <h2>B</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-letter="C">
    <h2>C</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regardless if I bubble up or propagate down and I put a console.log message in the event handler, the console.log() message is only ever fired once. Shouldn't it fire every time it hits a new element in the DOM tree?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *"*"See it in action here"* "* Please put your runnable examples **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: I see two logs for each click... Perhaps your browser is combining them with a number in the left margin? Well, I did before @Scott's edit, anyway...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't know why you see two messages per click. You shouldn't and I'm not.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Well, you commented one out...

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, I didn't. I just copied over from the Fiddle.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Look at the edit history -- you'll see I had put a snippet with both uncommented -- that's what my comment referred to. I don't copy from external sources because I feel it violates copyright (but IANAL).

Comment: They were uncommented in the original question (off-site resource notwithstanding), so I'd leave them uncommented when making the example runnable.

Answer (score 3):

> Regardless if I bubble up or propagate down and I put a console.log message in the event handler, the console.log() message is only ever fired once. Shouldn't it fire every time it hits a new element in the DOM tree?

None of your `div.container` elements is inside any of the others. Capture and propagation happen in ancestor/descendant hierarchies, not among siblings or other such.

If you put them inside one another, you'd see multiple messages:

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('div.container');


containers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log('I am fired');
  }, true);
});

// containers.forEach(container => {
//   container.addEventListener('click', e => {
//     console.log('I am fired');
//   }, false);
// });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="container" data-letter="A">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
    <div class="container" data-letter="B">
      <h2>B</h2>
      <span>Subtitle</span>
      <div class="container" data-letter="C">
        <h2>C</h2>
        <span>INNERMOST - click here</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a simpler example:

```js
const phaseName = {
    [Event.NONE]: "NONE",
    [Event.CAPTURING_PHASE]: "CAPTURING_PHASE",
    [Event.AT_TARGET]: "AT_TARGET",
    [Event.BUBBLING_PHASE]: "BUBBLING_PHASE",
};
function handler(e) {
    console.log(`div#${this.id} - ${phaseName[e.eventPhase] || "(unknown)"}`);
}
document.querySelectorAll("#container div").forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", handler, true);
    el.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">
        <div id="b">
            <div id="c">
                Click here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="d">
        <div id="e">
            <div id="f">
                Or here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you click "Click here", you see the event travel down through `#a` and `#b` to `#c`, then bubble up again. It doesn't pass through `#d`, `#e`, or `#f`. If you click "Or here", it travels through those and not `#a`, `#b`, and  `#c`.

Details in the [DOM UI Events spec](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/), which has [this section](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-flow) with this lovely diagram:

[image]